# How to use ros2 via wsl to webots in windows operating system?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, windows, webots

Hi i had recently started on ros2 and i had installed it on the wsl (linux) in windows operating system. I had also installed the webots robotic simulator in the windows instead in wsl (linux). So is there any way to use the ros2 that is present in wsl (linux) upon on the webots installed in windows operating system. If i can not then couldn't we use the ros2 on webots (windows package) instead of downloading the webots in wsl (linux) similar to ros2?

Thank you,

Karthik